# Access Denied using SCP; SSH is working

Tags: scp

I am trying to SCP from an ec2 instance to my laptop, ssh is working.

```
scp -2 ~/Downloads/NTLLSMON_TEST.pem ubuntu@publicdns.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:
/mnt/UAV_Images_Leith/reconstruction-with-image-size-2400-results
```

I keep getting this error not sure why ?

```
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

I have also tried using SCP -v but I am not sure how to read the out put.

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to@publicdns.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com @publicip  port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1
Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* 
compat         0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to @publicdns.ap-southeast-   
 2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256        
SHA256:AuPXVcbXJkSkbjbxMEWmVchcD1ru7066xPDWecP/w50
debug1: Host '@publicdns.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known   
and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/leithhawkins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: How are you trying to have SCP authenticate?  With a key?  If so, what file contains that key you are trying to use?  What are the filesystem's permissions settings for that file?

Comment: I am using the Same PEM key I am using to SSH the box when I Created The EC2 intance.  the file has had CHMOD 400 applied to it.

Comment: "the Same PEM key" did not tell me a key detail I asked for ("what file"?) (the answer is apparently ~/Downloads/NTLLSMON_TEST.pem), but Leith did provide that answer in a comment that he made by another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got wrong syntax. The path to key must be prefixed with `-i` switch:

```
scp -2i ~/Downloads/NTLLSMON_TEST.pem \
  ubuntu@publicdns.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/mnt/UAV_Images_Leith/reconstruction-with-image-size-2400-results .
```

Comment: ... and then led to another error, which I guess was quickly fixed thereafter (since this answer is accepted).  The other error is that I'm not seeing what file got transferred.  (I hadn't realized there was a space between the colon and the slash ; I thought it was just word-wrapping there.  That would have caused scp to try to upload the .pem file)  If you simply add a period after the colon, then this example could be valid.